# Applescript Error: Finder got an error: Can’t get folder "~/Library/Services"

Tags: applescript

Here is my code:

```
tell application "Finder"
move POSIX file "/Volumes/Toggle Desktop Icons/Toggle Desktop Icons/Install Files/Hide Icons.workflow" to folder "~/Library/Services"
end tell
```

And it always gets this error: Can’t get folder "~/Library/Services".

Any help?  This also needs to work on any mac I run the code on. Without changing the code

Thanks.

Comment: Replacing `~/` with the current user's home directory is a feature provided by Unix shells, not part of the POSIX standard for representing file system paths. Since you're in AppleScript, not sh/bash/whatever, you need to expand it yourself, e.g. `if mypath starts with "~/" then set mypath to (POSIX path of (path to home folder)) & (text 3 thru -1 of mypath)`. (That's not a complete or robust solution, btw - it'll choke on `"~/"` or "~USER/...", for example, but it should illustrate the point.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a system property `path to home folder` that you could use. And for simplicity sake use the native mac HFS path delimiter ":" to reference the rest of your path.

Try this (adding back in your full source path),

```
tell application "Finder"
  move POSIX file "/Volumes/.../Hide Icons.workflow" to folder (((path to home folder) as text) & "Library:Services")
end tell
```

Comment: You do not need StandardAdditions' `path to` command for this. Just use `move POSIX file "..." to home`. Or, since the OP wants `~/Library/Services` rather than `~/`, you could write `... to folder "Library:Services" of home`, although `... to (path to services folder)` would be better. Or you could even try using System Events (which I think may be fixed in 10.9 to do move/duplicate correctly), in which case it'd be `move disk item "/Volumes/.../Hide Icons.workflow" to folder "~/Library/Services"` (like the Unix shells, SE supports automatic path expansion).

Comment: Nice alternates @foo. Was going to edit, but yes not working for me on 10.7 so left as is. Still good to know SE is getting a lot of love.